# vaadin, allow new typed item in combobox

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I've faced with the issue with Vaasin's Combobox. I'd like to allow the user be able as select existed item from the list same provide his own value typing in the text field. I thought that it has to be easy, but... What I have now is

```
ComboBox roles = new ComboBox();
roles.setInputPrompt("Select Role");
roles.addItems(userService.getAllRoles());
roles.setImmediate(true);
roles.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
roles.setNewItemsAllowed(true);
formLayout.addComponent(roles);
```

Here I've found that `setNewItemsAllowed` allows such behavior, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. When I start typing some new value I can see an empty drop-down and when I select another field the value in checkbox reverts to prompt text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not enough to allow new items in the ComboBox.
You must alos set the new item handler, until you do so, the ComboBox has no way to know what a new item should look like.

```
roles.setNewItemHandler(....your handler....);
```

[Example code](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book#component.select.combobox.newitemhandler) and the [Docu for it](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-selection.html).

Comment: Hi Andre, thank you for your answer. On the page with example code I've found online example of configured ComboBox. I've tried to add new Item there, but it didn't work. I've added NewItemHandler into my code, bit it didn't help me as well. I can't understand where is the issue.

Comment: Sorry please, I've missed important step - to press Enter button, now it works fine, thanks.